# Spring 2013 Stack Overflow Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election, moderator-resignation

As foretold by Punxsutawney Phil, [Stack Overflow's Spring 2013 Community Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4) has come to an end. Your votes have been counted according to [the hallowed traditions of Meek STV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english), and the new moderators are:

[image: Andrew Barber]
[image: Flexo]
[image: Gordon]
[image: ChrisF]

Please give them a warm welcome, and lend them your support and advice as they learn the ropes.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/967088/0).

---

Also, I'd like to wish a fond farewell to three veteran moderators who are stepping down this year:

- **[Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267)** who has served since February of 2011.
- **[Tim Post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049)** who now works with us here at SE, and like Lasse has served since February 2011.
- And **[Jonathan Sampson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54680)** who has served since February of 2010.

These three have each done a lot for Stack Overflow over the years - please join me in thanking them for their service and wishing them all the best in their future adventures.

### Update:

Veteran moderator [Kev is stepping down after two years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181612/handing-back-my-mod-diamond) (almost to the day!) of hard work. We'll all miss him, but I'm happy to announce that runner-up in the election [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) has agreed to step up as a moderator.

[image: minitech]

Please give him a warm welcome as well!

Comment: Yay, now we can finally refer to @andrewbarber as "Evil Overlord".

Comment: @Bart the only question is what's required to beseech him to smite my foes....

Comment: Congratulations everybody! I'll go flag some stuff to get you started...

Comment: Congratulations and welcome to the new mods, and thanks to those who are stepping down (or up, I guess, in Tim's case).

Comment: Alright, now that you've got my vote, I assume *that thing has been taken care of*?  <wink wink> <j/k>

Comment: And @minitech I hope to see you back next election or maybe called up if the load gets too high. From the report below, it looks like you were very close

Comment: ... and thanks, Lasse, Tim, and Jonathan!

Comment: Congratulations everyone :)

Comment: Top ten was good - I wanted to vote for 4, but had to pick 3, and I'm glad who I would have picked 4th is still in anyway :) (and no - I'm not saying what order I cast my votes) - great to have you guys - good luck :)

Comment: If I'm reading the numbers right (http://www.opavote.org/results/967088/0), it looks like the runoff winners are no different than the popular vote winners (round 1). This assumes people would have voted the same way given one vote. Is that a typical outcome of ranked voting systems?

Comment: Congrats but I also expected Minitech/Raghav (an younger) too.

Comment: Congrats all - guess I am one of the average John Doe's who voted for 3 of the 4 new moderators... round it up to 4 if we were allowed to vote for that many, heh. :)

Comment: Welcome - thanks guys for keeping this place awesome!

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: WoW! All the 3 guys I voted are in this list, congrats guys.

Comment: I voted 1st Andrew 2nd ChrisF and 3rd. Gordon. Glad all the 3 I voted for are in. I would have voted for Raghav Sood too if he was a little older.

Comment: @minitech Well run! Sorry you didn't make it. Sorry you didn't make it.

Comment: @raghav Sorry to see you didn't make it. Keep up the good work and make another run next time.

Comment: Congratulations to everyone elected, and thank you for your unselfish contribution to the community! I hope you live up to your declarations during the election. 2 of my 3 votes helped elected new moderators :)

Comment: Congratulations for all :)

Comment: Congratulations to all newly elected Moderators..Keep up the good work! Thanks and a fond farewell to those three veteran moderators...  One again all the best to The **[Moderator Crew](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)** ....

Comment: Congratulations to all new moderators.

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: congrats @andrew barber and all of u...

Comment: My 2 votes are successful..and those are for @Andrew & Flexo, congratulations :)

Comment: Congratulations to every one... :)

Comment: Wow!! I can see my 2 out of 3 votes, were counted in winner buckets :) Andrew, Flexo.. Cheers!! guys..

Comment: Nice..! exactly the ones I voted for :)

Comment: Congratulations & Happy Moderating.

Comment: Well done to all the new moderators! Also very pleased to see @andrew-barber is already hard at work closing something I flagged :-)

Comment: Congratulations and Good Luck for newly elected Moderators and Happy Farewell for Veteran Moderators....:)

Comment: Wow..New Moderators!!!!!...Congratulations to all...

Comment: Awesome, happy to see that my vote didn't go waste. Congrats Andrew Flexo Gorden ChrisF. There is a lot to come ahead \m/

Comment: if (elected) "go work!" else "keep trying!"

Comment: My best wishes for all

Comment: Congratulations! So we got two from Europe (Gordon, ChrisF), one from the US (Andrew), and Flexo is from ???

Comment: Congratulations & a warm Welcome to Gordon, Chris, Andrew and Flexo as moderator! :)

Comment: Congrats everyone !

Comment: Good job, unbelievable results!

Comment: Congratulations to new moderators!

Comment: Why are veteran moderators leaving? Is this a concern?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: absolute power corrupts absolutely.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: I doubt it. Priorities change, folks realize that they may not have enough free time to do justice to their diamond. So they resign. No biggie.

Comment: Congratulations for the winners, for those that did not reached the Threshold, I wish them better lock next year and ... don't give up. @animuson I hope will see you candidature again next year.

Comment: Congrats to all!

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson was a StackOverflow rockstar. Fare thee well! And thanks for your contributions.

Comment: @ColonelPanic I can only speak for myself, but last year I bootstrapped a company on the side with a friend, creating apps for mobile devices. This process has eaten up most of my spare time, leaving me little motivated at the end of the day to sit down in front of a computer doing even more work. I informed the team about this last year after I had noticed this, and was told that I could sit tight and see what happened. This year, when election time came around, I vacated my spot to open it up for someone more motivated and able. I wish had more hours in each day, but alas :)

Comment: No girls? I think we should have some diversity. Also, I don't like that at least one moderator doesn't have their bio filled up - especially, location. If you're going to moderate, it helps to know some basic stuff about you.

Comment: @SagarHatekar: Only one ran, and I voted for her. The only female mod we've ever had was Anna Lear, who only lasted a couple of months before being hired as a community team member.

Comment: Congrats, as a n00b developer, I have no idea what I'd do without Stackoverflow. You guys are all awesome ^_^

Comment: @mmyers♦ I see. That's good to know, thanks!

Comment: Congrats to the elected folks. I hope its not too late to chime in your party!

Comment: Congrats to @minitech! I had been anticipating this since your high placement in the last election, and look forward to seeing you do well. :)

Comment: @minitech Perhaps you should change your about me?

Comment: @minitech - congrats on the diamond chap.

Comment: Congrats everyone :)

Comment: Looks like people are too trigger happy here with "pertains only to a specific site" reason...

Answer (score 79):

Here is the [OpenSTV](http://www.openstv.org/) report. If you prefer to create the report on your own or check that nothing fishy went on (let's start some nice conspiracy theories in the comments!), [get the data](https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/4) and re-run the election [locally](https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-openstv?os=pc).

```
Loading ballots from file stackoverflow-com-2013-election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 10 candidates and 6574 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 6574 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Stack Overflow Moderator Election 2013 using Meek STV.
10 candidates running for 4 seats.

 R|bluefeet     |ChrisF       |animuson     |Raghav Sood  |Andrew Barber|Lord Torgamus|JNK          
  |             |             |             |             |             |             |             
  |-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------
  |Flexo        |minitech     |Gordon       |Exhausted    |Surplus      |Threshold    
  |             |             |             |             |             |             
====================================================================================================
 1|   511.000000|   633.000000|   499.000000|   568.000000|  1261.000000|   477.000000|   368.000000
  |   750.000000|   568.000000|   939.000000|     0.000000|     0.000000|  1314.800001
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices.
====================================================================================================
 2|   557.000000|   665.000000|   538.000000|   599.000000|  1303.000000|   520.000000|             
  |   780.000000|   603.000000|   991.000000|    18.000000|     0.000000|  1311.200001
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating JNK and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 3|   598.000000|   717.000000|   632.000000|   643.000000|  1377.000000|             |             
  |   857.000000|   653.000000|  1057.000000|    40.000000|    70.199999|  1306.800001
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Lord Torgamus and transferring votes. All losing candidates are
  | eliminated. Candidate Andrew Barber has reached the threshold and is elected.
====================================================================================================
 4|   603.556820|   726.533260|   641.074440|   649.270540|  1306.800540|             |             
  |   875.046920|   662.635220|  1064.443080|    44.639180|     0.928375|  1305.872165
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Andrew Barber, 0.949020.
====================================================================================================
 5|             |   811.501880|   698.890120|   720.984260|  1399.804500|             |             
  |   941.066520|   727.654820|  1164.666600|   109.431300|   106.890759|  1292.913741
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating bluefeet and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 6|             |   826.430288|   712.948912|   730.912376|  1292.914200|             |             
  |   968.169552|   742.800632|  1176.986160|   122.837880|     2.681775|  1290.232425
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Andrew Barber, 0.876552.
====================================================================================================
 7|             |   924.257176|             |   828.998576|  1406.865960|             |             
  |  1074.613680|   825.602688|  1240.961328|   272.700592|   146.606078|  1260.259882
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating animuson and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 8|             |   945.905467|             |   843.796142|  1260.260445|             |             
  |  1112.064310|   848.986496|  1257.951126|   305.036014|    10.625975|  1253.792798
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Andrew Barber, 0.785209. Candidate Gordon has reached the threshold and is elected.
====================================================================================================
 9|             |   947.852977|             |   844.846060|  1254.240551|             |             
  |  1114.144302|   850.718788|  1254.540514|   307.656808|     2.243787|  1253.268639
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Andrew Barber, 0.781180 and Gordon, 0.996695.
====================================================================================================
10|             |  1039.847922|             |             |  1354.278063|             |             
  |  1219.533047|   962.268608|  1391.556674|   606.515686|   384.877195|  1193.496863
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Raghav Sood and transferring votes. All losing candidates are
  | eliminated. Candidate Flexo has reached the threshold and is elected.
====================================================================================================
11|             |  1112.071901|             |             |  1215.901605|             |             
  |  1253.643656|  1026.677022|  1212.831945|   752.873871|   189.701528|  1164.225226
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Andrew Barber, 0.688438; Flexo, 0.978651; and Gordon, 0.854836.
====================================================================================================
12|             |  1141.175236|             |             |  1180.327797|             |             
  |  1180.635431|  1057.698814|  1177.556362|   836.606360|    96.083403|  1147.478729
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Andrew Barber, 0.659180; Flexo, 0.908847; and Gordon, 0.820577.
====================================================================================================
13|             |  1156.658214|             |             |  1154.265369|             |             
  |  1157.447218|  1073.654851|  1153.577510|   878.396838|    65.465779|  1139.120633
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Andrew Barber, 0.640835; Flexo, 0.883324; and Gordon, 0.799618. Candidate ChrisF has
  | reached the threshold and is elected.

Winners are ChrisF, Andrew Barber, Flexo, and Gordon.
```

If you are curious how the system works, have a look at this great answer: [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77554/147015)

Comment: A conspiracy wouldn't be limited to just executing an improper query on the votes to determine the winner; any decent conspiracy would involve changing the actual data being queried, and thus re-running the query would create equally bogus results.

Comment: @Servy that's what the lizard people *want* you to think.

Comment: Shog already linked to that meta post

Comment: @Michael that's proof that he's one of them

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ummm... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Skies ?

Comment: @BenBrocka [They Live!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live)

Comment: Dangerous to have the `edit` option on this post.

Comment: You ... *eliminated* the losing candidates?  Oh dear.

Comment: Heh, the "eliminated" comment is recurring every time there's an election. I think last year I posted one.

Answer (score 55):

[I ran it on OpaVote as well](http://www.opavote.org/results/969080/0), which visualizes the election. You may need to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77554/147015) to understand how the voting works. Basically:

- The initial yellow bars show first preference votes
- if nobody is above the threshold, all votes on that user are transferred to other users (depending on the second or third preference) and the user is eliminated. The votes on the eliminated user are shown in red, and the transfer is in green.
- If a candidate goes above threshold, s/he is elected. If a fraction of the votes go extra, then this fraction is applied to the votes of each user who voted for the elected candidate, and transferred to their second (or third if the elected candidate was their second pref) choice. Again, the excess is shown by red, and the transfer in green.

[Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SZPq.png) in case the page gets deleted (I'm not exactly sure of how opavote works, there may be a chance that elections run on the free plan get deleted in 2 weeks). Note that the OpaVote page has useful mouseover tooltips, if it isn't deleted, use that :)

[image]

Comment: It's funny how the votes keep getting transferred to already elected candidates. "Yay! I'm elected!" "Sure, but have more votes" "Er... I don't need these, please give them to the rest" "OK, but take some more!" "But...but...I _don't need these_" "Yes, fine, I understand completely. TAKE MORE!" "Go home OpenSTV, you're drunk".

Comment: What kind of screens are these images optimized for? I'm afraid the pivot function of mine is not enough...

Comment: @theDmi: Use the link. It's interactive.

Comment: I know, it was meant as a joke :-)

Comment: @theDmi: Ah, oops :P

Comment: At first I wondered why Raghav Sood was eliminated when Exhausted had fewer votes..